# Find member variable using Locator in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

Qt Creator has the [Locator](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtcreator/creator-editor-locator.html) box, which allows you to easily find classes, methods, etc. Is there a way to use it to find class member variables, as well?

Using `. <expr>` will show member variables too, but that is only for searching inside the current file, not globally.

This the Locator:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

By default, there is not such feature, but as said in [the doc](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-editor-locator.html#creating-locator-filters) you can create a filter (I can't test it now, but I'll try this soon):

To create a locator filter:

1. In the locator, select Options > Configure to open the Locator options.
2. In the Filter Configuration dialog:

   1. Name your filter.
   2. Select at least one directory. The locator searches directories recursively.
   3. Define the file pattern as a comma separated list. For example, to search all .h and .cpp files, enter *.h, *.cpp
   4. Specify the prefix string.
3. To show only results matching this filter, select Limit to prefix.
4. Click OK.

Comment: Did you get it to work? I tried with this filter, but I have no idea what to put in the prefix string.

Answer (score 0):

QtCreator have no such feature - member variables are not good candidates for pivot points in search. If you want find usages of particular member, use "find symbol usages" (Ctrl+Shift+U when cursor is under symbol). If you want to find members of particular type, use usual search in regular expressions mode, something like:

```
\w+\s*\*\s*\w+\s*;
```

And limit scope to headers only (i.e use "*.h" file mask).

Comment: Qt Creator **can** search for member variables by typing `. <varname>` in the Locator, but for a single file only. So it already does have this feature. I'm not sure what you mean by *"member variables are not good candidates for pivot points in search"*. Class member variables are the same as class methods, it's just that they are variables instead of functions.

Comment: I'm awarding a bounty, but only for authoritative reference. If you want to, you could edit your question to provide sources stating that it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the 'Advanced...' option in the locator?  You can change the scope of the search to the Current Project, All Projects, Files on the System, etc.  I use this to even search for strings I use for debug output in my code.

Comment: Where is this "Advanced..." option? I couldn't find it.

Comment: When your cursor is in the window where you're editing your code hit ctrl+F.  This allows you to search for things in the current file.  There's an advanced option of the right side of this bar that pops up.

Comment: Also, if you can find where you've used the variable once, right click it and select "Find Usages."  This will list everywhere in the project this variable is used.